# firefox extension - How to read cookies in manifest v3

Tags: firefox, cookies, firefox-addon

I made an extension that reads cookies from the browser with manifest v3, it works fine on chromium but when i tried to add firefox support i wasn't able to read the browser's cookies.

I followed their example from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/getAll) and from [github](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/main/list-cookies) they work with v2 but not with v3...

this is the code I'm using in my app:

```js
async function Test() {
    let cookies = await browser.cookies.getAll({ domain: "twitter.com" });
    console.log(cookies);
}
```

this code doesn't raise an error, instead it returns an empty array.

and this is my manifest.json:

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "TGD",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "homepage_url": "https://github.com/cabiste69/DTG-extension",

    "icons": {
        "128": "./assets/images/icons/icon128.png",
        "96": "./assets/images/icons/icon96.png",
        "48": "./assets/images/icons/icon48.png",
        "16": "./assets/images/icons/icon16.png"
    },

    "action": {
        "default_icon": "./assets/images/icons/icon16.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "activeTab",
        "cookies",
        "storage"
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "*://*.twitter.com/"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When a manifest v3 extension is installed it is not granted any `host_permissions` by default<sup>1</sup> (unlike in Chrome).

In Firefox they can be enabled and disabled manually at any time by:

- Visit `about:addons` in the address bar
- Click on the extension
- Click the "permissions" tab
- Change the "Optional permissions for added functionality" toggles

As a developer it is possible to check and prompt for these using the [browser.permissions.contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/permissions/contains) and [browser.permissions.request()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/permissions/request) APIs.

For general reading see [permissions API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/permissions).

<sup>1</sup> I wonder if this only affects local development.